# git pull merging one branch into current branch

Tags: git, bitbucket

I created a repository with two developers. First developer created a new branch **mysql_login** and pushed a file. Other developer created a new branch **mysql_register** and pushed a file.

Now my questions:

1. Is it possible to pull another branch so that git branch command displays:

   master

   mysql_login

   mysql_register

My second developer was on branch **mysql_register** and executed the command:

```
git pull origin mysql_login
```

This command pulled files from branch **mysql_login** and merged into **mysql_register**

2. Is it possible to prevent second developer from pulling or pushing to branch **mysql_login**?

Like I can prevent users to access/pull/fetch other branches.

I hope I am clear with my questions

Thanks

Comment: Re 1, try `git fetch`, then `git branch -a`.  The `-a` flag makes sure remote branches are included in the list.  Re 2, this really depends on how your repo is hosted on the server, but you should try using `git fetch` instead of `git pull` if this is still confusing to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to pull another branch (...):

Use `fetch` and `checkout` commands to that.  `git fetch` will update repository status from remote and `git checkout <branchname>` will create a local copy of remote branch resulting in branch list you need

> Is it possible to prevent second developer from pulling or pushing to branch mysql_login?

You can set [branch restrictions](https://blog.bitbucket.org/2013/09/16/take-control-with-branch-restrictions/) with bitbucket, but I believe your problem can be solved with correct git usage - have non-shared user feature branches and have one developer merge progress into common codebase in `master` (or `development`) branch.

Your second developer should also do fetch and checkout another branch to prevent unwanted branch merges.

See for example [a simple git branching model](https://gist.github.com/jbenet/ee6c9ac48068889b0912).